# Multiple Juju environments on the same cluster

Tags: juju, maas

I recently deployed a MAAS/Juju environment based on a six nodes cluster, using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, to run a "proof of concept". I could appreciate how interesting the architecture is, and I'd like to understand if I can really base my future business on this technology. Therefore I'd like to understand more about any involved limitations, constraints and necessities.

In particular I'd like to understand if the same physical cluster can host multiple Juju environments, assuming openstack/virtualization is not used

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Massimo, yes, with recent MAAS and Juju packages, you can have multiple different Juju environments running using one MAAS controller.

When a Juju MAAS environment is bootstrapped, it gets an "agent-name", which is a created UUID.  This is then used to discriminate between different Juju environments, so a single user can have multiple non-overlapping Juju environments that don't accidentally step on each other's toes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not the right person to answer your question but I quickly asked around and by default MaaS supports one Juju environment and via manual providers you could run multiple in a more manual fashion.

I am interested in understanding your use case to see if support for multiple Juju environments for MaaS should go into our roadmap.

Please contact me at maarten dot ectors at canonical dot com.

regards,
Maarten